# Querying nested collection in RavenDb document

Tags: c#, lucene, ravendb

I have a filter method using Lucene extensions for a list of `Store` documents with the following structure:

```
 public class Store {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

  }

  public class Product {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public double Price { get; set; }
  }
```

my filter method:

```
    public IEnumerable<Store> Filter(string term = null)
    {
        var query = session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Store>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
        {
            var search = $"*{term}*";
            var escapeQueryOptions = EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards;

            query = query
                .Search(n => n.Name, search, escapeQueryOptions)
                .OrElse()
                .Search(n => n.Url, search, escapeQueryOptions)
                .OrElse()
                .Search(n => n.Address, search, escapeQueryOptions);
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Now I would like to allow the filter by product's name but I'm unable to figure out how to express this with lucene.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a dropping down to Lucene via DocumentQuery? You can do full text searches, and filtering, using the standard API?